# Cómo puedo descargar un archivo pdf en puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, puppeteer

Necesito descargar un archivo al que se tiene acceso luego de enviar un formulario.
Puedo ejecutar la descarga del archivo con la función `page.click(selector)` pero luego viene de camino `browser.close()` y lo cierra antes de que termine de descargar.

Cómo puedo ejecutar la descarga para saber cuando terminó y luego cerrar el browser?

Estoy usando `headless: false` por ahora, pero necesito que funcione en ambas modalidades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente lo **solucioné** usando `node-fetch` y algunas utilidades para escribir archivos.

```
// ...

const fs = require( 'fs' )
const util = require( 'util' )
const stream = require( 'stream' )

const fetch = require( 'node-fetch' )


// ...

await page.waitForSelector( field.download )
const fetchURL = await page.$eval( field.download, download => download.href )

// Manage permission download via async fetch
await ( async () => {

    // Download the pdf permission
    const response = await fetch( fetchURL )

    // Prepare streamline
    const streamPipeline = util.promisify( stream.pipeline )
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream( `${ config['download-path'] }/permisov-${ Date.now() }.pdf` )

    // Save file to disk
    streamPipeline( response.body, writeStream )

})()
```

`field.download` es mi selector html que importo desde un objeto.

Node-fetch: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch

Las demás utilidades están disponibles en node.

Answer (score 3):

Entre el click y el browser.close() está la demora de la descarga del archivo del servidor, cierto? Entonces sería mejor controlar la petición de descarga para que una vez que lo tengas en memoría, pasarlo de ahí al guardado en la pc es directo. Podrías usar una funcion como está:

```
const downloadFile = () => {
   return fetch('urlRequest', configRequest).then(res=>res.blob)
}
```

Esa función te devolvería una promesa con el blob del archivo. Recuerda que para poder hacer esa función con éxito debes inspeccionar bien la anatomía de la petición que hace el equivalente click que mencionaste.

Después podrías crear una url con ese blob:

```
const blob = await downloadFile()
const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

Con eso ya puedes asignarlo al atributo de "href" de un elemento "ancor"  con atributo "download". Para luego ejecutar su método click y descargar a la pc, pero como la data ya está en local el proceso es inmediato por lo que browser.close() ya no te ganará.

El proceso de descarga sería algo así en general:

```
//... 
await page.evaluate(async () => {
   const downloadFile = () => fetch('url').then(res=>res.blob)
   const createURL = blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob)
   const saveFile = href => {
      const a = document.createElement('a')
      a.href = href
      a.download = 'descarga.txt' // pon la extensión correspondiente.
      a.click()
   }
   const mainDownload = async () => {
      const blob = await downloadFile()
      const href = createURL(blob)
      saveFile(href)
   }
   await mainDownload()
})
await browser.close();
```

Sin embargo, para eso no te olvides poner antes la ruta de descarga con:

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
   behavior: 'allow',
   downloadPath: '/root/project/app/your_download/'
});
```

No he probado el código así que quizá haya algun error de sintaxis, pero la idea en sí debería funcionar ya que estos requerimientos suelen ser recurrentes y esta suele ser la forma correcta o al menos así lo hacemos en mi trabajo.

De todas formas espero haberte ayudado. Saludos (Y)

Comment: Gracias la por ayuda, lo tomé como base para llegar a otra solución!!